# randomly generate a matrix with fixed number of non zero values using python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I want to generate a random matrix (min value=0, max value=25, steps=5) with N rows and 6 columns, where the number of non-zero values (k) given as input.

Example:

Input:
N=2
K=8

Output (result):
[[ 5,  0, 20,  0, 15, 25],
[ 0, 15, 15,  0, 25, 10]]

I tried to generate the matrix with the code: np.random.choice(np.arange(0,20, 5), size=(2, 6)) but I can't controll the number of non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will generate an array of the shape you want with non-zero values everywhere, then it will insert the right amount of zeroes at random places.

```py
def generate_matrix(N, K):
    arr = np.random.choice( np.arange(5,26,5), size=(N,6))
    # inputs 6*N-K zeroes at random (unique) places
    np.put(arr, np.random.choice(arr.size, size=arr.size-K, replace=False), 0)
    return arr.tolist()
```

Comment: (1) This will never generate `25`s. (2) `np.random.randint(1, 6, size=(N, 6)) * 5` may be faster than `np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 30, 5), size=(N, 6))` (3) `arr[:K] = 0;
np.random.shuffle(arr)` (on ravelled array, then reshaping) may be faster than `np.put()`

Comment: @miri you mean you want the result as a list?

Comment: It works now when get the result directly without using print.

Comment: Have edited my answer to return the output as a list (of lists). Also, indeed, there was a bug and it did not fill entries with value `25`. Fixed that too.

Comment: It works with print after using tolist(). For the value 25, I used 30 as the max value to get the 25 value because the step is 5: arr = np.random.choice(np.arange(5,30,5), size=(N,6))

Comment: @mlri with step 5 any stop value between 26 and 30 (both included) produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast approach could be:

```
import typing as typ
import numpy as np


def gen_rand_matrix(
    num_non_zeros: int,
    rows: int,
    cols: int = 6,
    non_zero_vals: typ.Sequence = tuple(range(5, 26, 5)),
    seed: typ.Union[None, int] = None
) -> list:
    size = rows * cols
    non_zero_vals = np.asarray(non_zero_vals)
    # : only zeros
    if num_non_zeros <= 0:  
        return np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=non_zero_vals.dtype)
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    indices = rng.integers(len(non_zero_vals), size=size)
    arr = non_zero_vals[indices]
    # : some zeros must be set
    if num_non_zeros < size:
        arr[:-num_non_zeros] = 0
        rng.shuffle(arr)
    return arr.reshape((rows, cols)).tolist()
```

Which essentially creates a random array with all valid values, then zeros a part of the array, and shuffles it.

The `.tolist()` is to convert the result to a `list`. Otherwise, the result is a NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

To fill ypur matrix in the desired way I would first fill the entire matrix with non-zero values

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(5,20, 5), size=(2, 6))
```

then fill in the zeros  by randomly selecting their respective row and columns.
Don't forget to check if there already is a zero at your new generated zero-position, in that case you need to genarate another random row-column pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```py
import numpy as np


def generate_random_matrix(N, k):
    # Create an N x 6 matrix filled with zeros
    matrix = np.zeros((N, 6), dtype=int)

    # Generate k distinct random indices
    indices = np.random.choice(N * 6, k, replace=False)

    # Fill the selected indices with random values in the range [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
    for index in indices:
        row = index // 6
        col = index % 6
        matrix[row, col] = np.random.choice(list(range(0, 26, 5)))

    return matrix


# Example usage:
N = 2
k = 8
result = generate_random_matrix(N, k)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check below code


import numpy as np

def generate_matrix(N, k):
    total_elements = N * 6  # total elements in a N x 6 matrix

    non_zero_positions = np.random.choice(total_elements, k, replace=False)
    

    array = np.zeros(total_elements)
    

    array[non_zero_positions] = np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 26, 5), k)

    matrix = array.reshape(N, 6)
    return matrix.astype(int)

N = 2
k = 8
result = generate_matrix(N, k)
print(result)
```